# Is there any general integration test framework for console java application?

Tags: java, integration-testing

For example, I am going to write an application. Its core requirement is simple. It keeps scanning a folder. If new files arrive, it will transfer it to a FTP site. It will be written in JAVA as a console application.

I am wondering if there is integration test framework, like open source one, for this kind of application? It should be capable of testing the following sameple test cases.

1. Generate files, then check if these files are transferred to FTP.
2. If FTP is down, can the application report corresponding warning logs?
3. etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) combined with some mocking framework, like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) should get you a fair bit on your way. If you want to take it further, for instance having actual instances running of external service, you can use JUnit combined with, for instance, [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/) to start up Java EE containers as part of your test. Light-weight, in-memory databases like [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) is often used as placeholder databases for integration tests.

I've heard some people using JBoss [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian/), but haven't tried it myself. It's more for remote testing of Java EE components though, so might not fit your exact requirement.

Comment: +1 JUnit, Mockito, and HSQLDB should handle all that's mentioned here in this question.

Comment: But what? I think you only posted part of your comment.

Comment: Wow... something wrong with Stackoverflow.  It looks a little complicated for my scenario. Actually what I need is like below. 1. This ITF can launch my app. 2.before/after/during launching my app, I can write some custom code/script to do prepare/check things.

Comment: I would look at using some continuous integration platform, like Hudson or team city. I suspect this is what you're really after when you say "integration test framework". It's basically a central server that runs your build (and your JUnit tests, for instance).

Comment: Thanks, pap. I am going to utilize testNG, mockito and CruiseControl to do my job. :)

Comment: Sounds like a fairly standard setup. Good luck!